# DotNetNuke UserInfo.Membership.IsOnLine is always false even after login

Tags: dotnetnuke, membership

I am trying to get user's online status during login. I am checking following property after ValidateUser, but it always return false.

```
    objUser.Membership.IsOnLine
```

Just to confirm, i put following code in one of my module that can be accessed *ONLY* after login.

```
    Dim _currentUser As UserInfo = DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserController.GetCurrentUserInfo()
    Dim message as String = IIf(_currentUser.Membership.IsOnLine, "Online", "Not Online")
    UI.Skins.Skin.AddModuleMessage(Me, message, Skins.Controls.ModuleMessage.ModuleMessageType.BlueInfo)
```

It always show 'Not Online', while user is logged in.
Am i missing something?
Please help.

I am using DNN 6.02.05 Community Ed.

Comment: logically GetCurrentUser is always online, not sure what you are trying to achieve here

Comment: Hi Prashant, I am trying to prevent user from login if that is already login from another location/terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Important steps to Enable Online Users in DotNetNuke

The “Users Online” module works on a background thread (via the scheduler) to add and expire users from the users online list. The scheduled job should exist in your installation, but it is disabled by default.

To enable the scheduled job:-

1. Login to your portal as a Super User account (e.g. host)
2. Navigate to Host -> Schedule
3. Edit the “DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.PurgeUsersOnline, DOTNETNUKE” job (click the pencil)
4. Check “Scheduled Enabled”
5. Click Update
6. Click 'run now' to get effect on the spot.

Now that you have configured the scheduled job, your users should begin to process background users. The problem is that there is an additional host setting you must set before this can occur.

To enable users online:-

1. Login to your portal as a Super User account (e.g. host)
2. Navigate to Host -> Host Settings
3. Expand “Other Settings”
4. Check “Enable Users Online”
5. Click Update

Answer (score 1):

maybe a dumb question, but did you check whether users online feature is turned on in the host settings  --> other settings?